# FileZilla : how to get server Status with date and time?

Tags: filesystems, filezilla

I am using `FileZilla`, for free open source FTP and FTPS Server. If I am doing something's with data, like data transfer or data deleting, the all status I am getting above on the FileZilla (Please see the `picture` below). I am exciting to know, how we will get server `Status along with Date and Time`?

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuwmm.png)
[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message window can show the time but not the date. To show the time got to Edit -> Settings -> Logging, then enable `Show timestamps in message log`.

[image: IMG:]

[image: Filezilla - Message window]

However, if you enable `Log to file`, time and date will be stored. Open the log file to view the logged messages with the times and dates.

[image: IMG:]